# Trouble in getting JSONObject to String Array Value

Tags: java, android, json, android-viewpager, arrays

Hi i am having trouble to get the JSONObject value title and store into the array.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
{   
// JSON Node names
     private static final String TAG_CATEGORIESLIST = "categorylist";
     private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
     private static final String TAG_URL = "url";
     public static String[] titles;
     public final Context context;
     public int[] scrollPosition;
     JSONArray categories = null; 
     JSONObject json;
     {
         try {
                JSONFunction JSONFunction = new JSONFunction();
               json = JSONFunction.categorylist();
               // Getting Array of Categories
               categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIESLIST);
                // looping through All Categories
               for(int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String url = c.getString(TAG_URL); 
                titles = new String[] {title}; //only obtain one result
                scrollPosition = new int[titles.length];
            }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
     }
...
```

My `titles` only get one value, need some help from u guys.

Addon:

I am using Viewpagerindicator library, the default code to display the title is like tat

> private static String[] titles = new String[] { "Page 1", "Page 2",
>                           "Page 3", "Page 4", "Page 5"};

I am trying to input json data into there.
Thanks.

Comment: can you show me your api or json data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not incrementing the titles array

Change this

```
 titles = new String[] {title};//Because of this your last retrived  value will be stored in titles
```

to

```
 titles[i] = title;
```

Comment: i got error after change tat line of code. threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
E/AndroidRuntime(29164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(29164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kwongwahnews/com.example.demo.ViewPagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: initialize you titles with String[] titles= new String[givesizehere];

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
{   
// JSON Node names
     private static final String TAG_CATEGORIESLIST = "categorylist";
     private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
     private static final String TAG_URL = "url";
     public static String[] titles;
     public final Context context;
     public int[] scrollPosition;
     JSONArray categories = null; 
     JSONObject json;
     {
         try {
                JSONFunction JSONFunction = new JSONFunction();
               json = JSONFunction.categorylist();
               // Getting Array of Categories
               categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIESLIST);
                // looping through All Categories
               for(int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String url = c.getString(TAG_URL); 

change this line in your code
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////

```
                titles[i]=title;
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////
                    scrollPosition = new int[titles.length];
                }

```
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
     }
```

Comment: i got error after change tat line of code. threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
E/AndroidRuntime(29164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(29164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kwongwahnews/com.example.demo.ViewPagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException